# What is the importance of using Contact roles related list on Account layout?

Tags: account

Could anyone give the clarity on Contact roles?

Basically why we add contact role related list in Account layout?

Comment: I recommend you the module Account & Contacts in Trailhead => https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/admin_intro_accounts_contacts

Comment: in addition to the above comment, I would suggest reading this [article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=contactroles.htm&type=0). @benahm: I would suggest to post your comment as answer with more details and some excerpts from the articles to help the OP and anyone who visits understand. :)

Comment: @Mahmood ok done ;)

Comment: for example account is company : ABC company and ceo, directores etc people are tagged into contact role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contact role related list helps link & define the role of each contact on a given account (**even if the contact does not belong to the account**)

As displayed down here I am on the **Acme Corporation** and I linked contacts from the current account & other accounts to this account

For more information checkout those links

- [Account & Contacts (Thrailhead)](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/admin_intro_accounts_contacts)
- [Considerations for Using Contact Roles (Help)](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=contactroles.htm&type=0)

[image]